# jQuery MiniColors 2.1 - get rgba value

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Documentation is quite odd to me. I have no ideas how do I get rgba value on change event.

**Plugin settings sample:**

```
$('.colorpicker').minicolors({
  changeDelay: 200,
  letterCase: 'uppercase',
  control: 'wheel',
  opacity: true,
  theme: 'bootstrap',
  change: function (hex, opacity) {
    console.log('HEX: ' + hex + ' OPACITY: ' + opacity);
  }
});
```

But that is obviously retrieving value of hex and opacity. However I found this in documentation:

```
Use this syntax for calling methods:

$(selector).minicolors('method', [data]);
```

And then there is a method, which I have no ideas how to use within my plugin settings.

```
rgbString & rgbaString
Returns an RGB or RGBA string suitable for use in your CSS. Examples:

rgb(0, 82, 148)
rgba(0, 82, 148, .75)
```

Any ideas about this, I searched for a while to see if any answer is provided actually, but I found only some functions for converting hex to rgba. Guess that was useful in older versions of this plugin, however right now there is a function from within a plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can get rgba by calling `minicolors` with `rgbaString` parameter like this:

```
$('selector').minicolors('rgbaString')
```